# Does it make sense to use interface when there are different generic types

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

Using interface is good approach to provide abstraction and I am usually trying to use it if possible. But this time I have a little bit different case and I am not sure if it is good practice to use here.

I have two different classes which needs some query method with same signature. Lets say MyString and MyInteger.

I was thinking to define an interface with one method:

```
public interface MyInterface{

   // no type is specified for the list, because each implementation will have different type of object
   List query();  
}
```

So basically I need to implement two different class which implements the interface above. First one will get `List<String>`, and second one will get `List<Integer>` result from the query method.

The thing is I do not like not specifying generic type of in the interface, because I will need to cast later.

So does it make sense to use interface here, or better to implement two separate class with same method signature without common interface ?

Comment: Why isn't it `MyInterface<T>` with `List<T>`? What do you mean "cast later"? That sounds like your design is wrong (or you're misunderstanding how the interface type affects things).

Comment: *"The thing is I do not like not specifying generic type of in the interface, because I will need to cast later."* What do you mean by that? Can you show us the thing you think is a problem? Because on the face of it, `MyInterface` should take a generic parameter it applies to the return of `query`, as Kayaman said.

Comment: When I need to get the object from list lets say Integer x = (Integer)list.get(index); This is just an example, indeed I use user defined object.

Comment: not sure if "method with same signature" is the best reason for having an interface. more a question of what is being modeled (*semantic*?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The thing is I do not like not specifying generic type of in the interface...

That's exactly how you address this.

> When I need to get the object from list lets say Integer x = (Integer)list.get(index); This is just an example, indeed I use user defined object.

The whole point of generics is that you **don''t** need to do that. Instead:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    List<T> query();  
}

public class MyInteger implements MyInterface<Integer> {
    // ...
}

// ...
MyInteger foo = new MyInteger();

// ...
List<Integer> list = foo.query();

// ...
Integer i = list.get(index);
```

Or with `var`, since it's been in the language a while now:

```
// ...
var foo = new MyInteger();

// ...
var list = foo.query();

// ...
var i = list.get(index);
```

> So does it make sense to use interface here, or better to implement two separate class with same method signature without common interface ?

That depends. If you will have several classes that will implement `MyInterface<Integer>` and you need to deal with instances of those classes in a common way (e.g., so you refer to them with `MyInterface<Integer>` rather than the class) and/or if `MyInterface` represents some basic aspect of your overall structure, then probably it makes sense to use an interface. If you don't, if it's just that you're going to have two different classes with `List<something> query` methods, it may not. It depends on the overall design and (a bit) on style.